# Get serverTimestamp from Firestore with UTC format

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I'm trying to read serverTimestamp that I stored in firestore with flutter. I stored the timestamp with this code:

```
final docUser =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("posts").doc(tittle_cont.text);
      final json = {
        "title": tittle_cont.text,
        "content": content_cont.text,
        "category": category,
        "date": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), // << that's the way i did it
      };
      await docUser.set(json);
```

On firestore, if i check the value "date" of the document that I am reading, I get:

28 de Febrero de 2023,17:39:30 UTC-3 // << that is fine, that format works for me

But on the app, to read the value I used:

```
Text("Date: " +(data['date'] as Timestamp).toDate().toLocal().toString()),
```

and I get as value for example:

2023:02:38 22:26:43.287

That could be fine, but I don't like that number .287, I prefer to get the UTC instead that part.

Or if its possible, I want to get the value as I can see it on firestore, like this:

```
28 de Febrero de 2023,17:39:30 UTC-3
```

I have been trying different ways but i can't resolve this issue.

I'd like to know how can achieve this, Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried using DateFormat?  I'm not seeing an example here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateFormat` form `intl` package

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

Timestamp timestamp = data['date'] as Timestamp;
DateTime dateTime = timestamp.toDate();
String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd MMMM y,HH:mm:ss Z').format(dateTime);

Text("Date: " + formattedDate),
```